# i am trying to install openstack for first time in my virtual box ubuntu VM

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, openstack

i am getting this error while installing open stack, i am following this installation guide, https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/install-openstack-on-ubuntu. you can see the errors in my screenshot.

This error from my system i copied text from my error screen

```
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:1273: start_ovn_services /opt/stack/devstack/lib/neutron-legacy:521:start_ovn /opt/stack/devstack/lib/neutron_plugins/ovn_agent:714:wait_for_sock_file
/opt/stack/devstack/lib/neutron_plugins/ovn_agent: 191:die
[ERR OR] /opt/stack/devstack/lib/neutron_plugins/ovn_agent: 191 Socket /var/run/openvswitch/ovnnb_db.sock not found
Error on exit
/opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py:22: DeprecationWarning: The distutils pack age is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
from distutils import spawn
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-10-1353101.txt for details
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? From your question "DeprecationWarning: The distutils pack age is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives from distutils import spawn World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-10-1353101.txt for details" Did you look into this?